# Write tableview contents to PDF file

Tags: pdf

I am developing iPad application in which I want to create PDF file from Tableview contents. I searched lot but not able to find out the solution.
Any one solved this issue?

Or

Is it possible to write HTML string (convert tableview contents to HTML string) to PDF so I can experience the same look of tableview.
I tried this but its showing me the plain HTML string.